# AMPscript button to delete records

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I working on a small project using HTML CSS and AMPscript to pull records from a Data extension and display it in a table which is already done but I want to make it possible to delete those records with the click of a button[image: showing 1 record with trash bin to delete]

the code looks like this

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">ID</th>
  <th scope="col">First Name</th>
  <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
  <th scope="col">Email</th>
  <th scope="col">Phone</th>
  <th scope="col">Business Unit</th>
  <th scope="col">Actions</th>

</tr>
</thead>
   <tbody>
 %%[
     set @DEname = "DemoSeedList"
     set @listcount = "seedlist"
     set @rows = LookupRows(@DEname,"ListCount", @listcount)
     set @rowCount = RowCount(@rows)
     
     if @rowCount > 0 then
      for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
        var @firstname, @lastname, @id, @email, @phone, @businessunit, @listcount

        set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
        set @id = field(@row,"Id")
        set @listcount = Field(@row,"Listcount")
        set @firstname = Field(@row,"FirstName")
        set @lastname = Field(@row,"LastName")
        set @email = Field(@row,"Email")
        set @phone = Field(@row,"Phone")
        set @businessunit = field(@row,"BusinessUnit")      
]%%
<tr>
  <td id="tobedel" name="tobedel">%%= v(@id) =%%</td>
  <td>%%= v(@firstname) =%%</td>
  <td>%%= v(@lastname) =%%</td>
  <td>%%= v(@email) =%%</td>
  <td>%%= v(@phone) =%%</td>
  <td>%%= v(@businessunit) =%%</td>
  <td class="text-center">
    <button type="button">
     <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>         
    </button>
  </td>
%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ endif ]%%
</tr>
</tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

by using a for loop pulls one record at a time and adds it as a table row. What I need help with is by using the trash bin action how can I delete that specific record

Comment: Did you check the [DeleteData](https://ampscript.guide/deletedata/) function?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use JavaScript to add an onclick event to the trash bin button, which calls a function that sends an HTTP request to the Marketing Cloud REST API to delete the record.